# program links VS programs links

Tags: grammar

If I wanted to say: `this folder contains the links to all the programs`,

should I use: `this folder contains the program links` or `this folder contains the programs links` ?

Comment: The answer is addressed in [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138273/list-of-items-is-correct-is-items-list-correct/139128#139128) post. Essentially, singular nouns are chosen for attributive duty (though there is the odd exception).

Comment: This question has been asked dozens of times before. See e.g. [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1314?lq=1), or the many related questions linked from these.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the first option........"links" is plural, and "program" acts as an adjective in this context, describing the common type of links.  Because the common type is singular, the **s** is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'this folder contains all the program links' thus avoiding whether to have to use the plural form of 'program' (or the singular possessive "program's" or plural possessive "programs' " form, which would be even more correct as the links are those of the programs).

Having said that, your original question 'this folder contains the links to all the programs' is also absolutely fine!